# how can I find a shortest line (2 end points will be fine) from a group of points which is intersect with another given line segment

Tags: algorithm

[image: Picture]

Say I got a bunch of points(red points) and a blue **line segment**, i want to find a line(2 points) which is intersect with the blue **line segment** and the sum of two end points' perpendicular distance to the blue **line segment** is the shortest distance .

P in this picture above is CD and the blue **line segment** intersect point.

I only know that they should be on the blue line's different side (left/right or above/below).

But there are still serveral variants can make this go south.Like AB and CE in this picture.

Edit : At first i thought i only need to make sure both of two end points' projection point lies on the blue **line segment**.But if I do so,there might be not so many good points for this case.I might just throw the only solution away.

Edit2 : The background is about image processing.Find 2 reliable points (say line **M**) near given line segment say **L**,if they intersect with each other then in another image they still does.It's about find line **L**'s candidates in another image.

Edit3 :
Some python codes,but it's just my first thought.

It's not finished so it's not tested yet.

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self.point = (0, 0)
        self.dist = float(Inf)

    def update(self, point, dist):
        self.point = point
        self.dist = dist


    for l0 in lines0:
        # contains shortest perpendicular distance point on each side
        temp = [Point(), Point()]
        for p0 in points0:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = l[0]
            # define given line L
            line = lsrl.Line(lsrl.Point(x1, y1),
                             lsrl.Point(x2, y2))

            # define point from points
            point = lsrl.Point(p0[0], p0[1])

            # perpendicular distance
            dist = lsrl.distToLine(line, point)

            # which side on return 0,1,2
            side = lsrl.determineSide(line, point)
            # lies on the given line
            if side == 2:
                pass
            if dist < temp[side].dist:
                # meet a better point then update
                temp[side].update(p0, dist)
```

Comment: AB is shorter than CD. Why are you saying that CD is the correct solution?

Comment: @Stef AB does not intersect with the blue line segment,it's not goes infinity.I didnt mean CD is the right answer, I just draw some possible cases.CF is the correct solution.

Comment: Oh. I have a very simple arithmetic solution using cross-product and dot-product, but it doesn't take into account the "doesn't intersect with the line segment" issue.

Comment: @Stef Yes I read some similar topics.If this line goes infinity all i have to do is calculate shortest perpendicular distance on both side.

Comment: What exactly do you need to solve this task? Just an idea? Basic pseudo code? Mathematical background? How detailed?

Comment: @Markus I added background and codes in the main body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch of algorithm:

1. Calculate all perp. distances including orientation (left or right of dividing line L).
2. Devide points into two lists (left or right).
3. Sort both lists by perp. distance.
4. Now build pairs from both lists, sorted by minimal sum of perp. distance.
5. Choose the first (smallest sum) pair with a connecting line that intersects L as result.

Comment: Does step 4 means formulate a Cartesian product?

Comment: As we have sorted the lists by distance we don’t need to calculate the full cartesian product but we can start with the smallest sum and try each pair by increasing sum. But of course in case that only the largest sum leads to intersection, it will be the whole n x m space.

Comment: Thanks for the clarify ! This seems to be the best solution now.